# Full stack , Stack Exchange etc, What is stack ??

Tags: stack

This might be silly and non technical.

This website name is "stack"overflow and there is "stack"exchange. In one of the job portals I saw a new term "Full Stack Developer". In one of the presentations of an IT giant, there were talking about the stacks like "Server", "Storage" , "Applications".

Stack is just one word and it is being used differently in different situations. All I know is that it is a LIFO data structure and plays a vital role in many system operations.
Can someone throw some light on this ?? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Stack is also used in technology to describe the collection of technologies used to solve a problem or build an app.  For example the 'MEAN' stack is MongoDB, Express, Angularjs and Nodejs.  The 'LAMP' stack is Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP.  And so on... 
The original meaning of stack is just a pile of things, eg: a stack of cards.

Comment: Don't forget waffles!